# Calling a macro several times

Tags: sas

I have a pretty large macro that I want to call several times. (I'm using replicate weights to calculate my error.) I want to call the process for different variables, say VAR1-VAR99. In the past I've used a DATA *NULL* step and CALL EXECUTE like so:

```
data _null_;
  do i=1 to 99;
    call execute(compress("%mymacro(VAR" || i || ")") );
    end;
  run;
```

This isn't working for me this time, though. There might be something I'm missing about the scope of macro variables? I'd like to call:

```
%mymacro(VAR1)
%mymacro(VAR2)
...
%mymacro(VAR99)
```

and of course I'd like to do this without 99 lines of code. Why might my method be suddenly failing me? What are other ways to do this?

Comment: When you say it isn't working, do you get a warning or error in the log?  Can you make a small sample macro that illustrates the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use call execute, try to call macro program in macro program.

```
%macro repeat(n);
    %do i=1 %to &n;
         %mymacro(VAR&i);
    %end;
%mend;
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of generating macro calls with call execute.  I added %NRSTR, as it prevents macro timing issues.  It makes the call execute generate the macro call, without actually executing the macro.  If your macro generates macro variables from data, without the %NRSTR you can end up with timing issues and scope issues.

```
%macro mymacro(var) ;
  %put var=&var  ;
%mend mymacro ;

data _null_;
  do i=1 to 5;
    call execute(cats('%nrstr(%mymacro(var',i,"))")) ;
  end;
run;
```

Or it could be as simple as changing your code to use single quotes instead of double quotes.  Single quotes will prevent the macro from executing when the data step compiles.  If your macro does not generate macro variables from data, this may be enough.  But I always use %NRSTR.

```
data _null_;
  do i=1 to 5;
    call execute(compress('%mymacro(VAR' || i || ")") );
  end;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Large** is probably the key word in that question. Let me explain.

You are pushing the macro calls onto the stack using `call execute()`.  But what actually is getting placed on the stack is the code generated by the macro and not the call. Look at the lines with `+` at the beginning in the SAS log.

If the macro generates just a few lines of code then not much is stacked up to run after the data step.  But if it is **large** then you might overload the stack.

Also if the macro uses the lines of SAS code it generates to create macro variables (using `call symputx()` or SQL's `into` clause) that later drive the macro's logic there will be a timing issue. Again that is more likely to happen with a **large** macro than a small (simple) macro.

Wrap the macro call (or at least the macro's name) in `%nrstr()` will prevent SAS from running the macro during the `call exucute()` call. Instead the macro call will placed onto the stack to be run after the data step finishes.

Consider this simple macro definition.

```
%macro mymacro(varname);
proc means data=sashelp.class ;
  var &varname ;
run;
%mend mymacro;
```

If I use `call execute()` to generate calls to it like this:

```
data _null_;
  call execute('%mymacro(age)');
  call execute('%mymacro(height)');
  call execute('%mymacro(weight)');
run;
```

Then you will see lines like this in the SAS log

```
1    + proc means data=sashelp.class ;   var age ; run;
2    + proc means data=sashelp.class ;   var height ; run;
3    + proc means data=sashelp.class ;   var weight ; run;
```

But if instead you add `%nrstr()` like this:

```
data _null_;
  call execute('%nrstr(%mymacro)(age)');
  call execute('%nrstr(%mymacro)(height)');
  call execute('%nrstr(%mymacro)(weight)');
run;
```

Then the lines in the SAS log look like this.

```
1    + %mymacro(age)
2    + %mymacro(height)
3    + %mymacro(weight)
```